# How to display gif while GridView Process ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, gridview

I have an application that displays various data in an ASP.NET GridView. The values ​​are displayed as a selection of combobox. When I select comobo box, the reload process is taking about 8 seconds. I would like to display a gif of load before starting the process and end it cancel the display image. I tried to use a thread for this, but it did not work very well. Could someone help me?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //My Image
        imageLoad.Visible = true;
        Assembly myAsm = Assembly.Load("PainelBordo");
        AssemblyName aName = myAsm.GetName();
        Version version = aName.Version;

        BusinessLogicLayer bll = new BusinessLogicLayer();

        LoadDDLWRTG(CreateDataTableWRTGList());
        LoadDataPBList();

        TimerRefresh.Interval = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimerInterval"].ToString());

        lblUpdateDate.Text = "Refresh " + bll.DateUpdateFormat(DateTime.Now);
        // My image
        imageLoad.Visible = false;
    }
```

Combobox SelectedIndexChanged.

```
protected void ddlWRTGroup_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page_Load(sender, e);
    }
```

Comment: you need to do it on the client side, by `show` / `hide` that image before loading or posting...

Comment: simple javascript is enough, but all goes to what and how are you posting... as "a series of dropdowns" I would always do it better, as an ajax call, and those 8 seconds would make 3...

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop a Button(**btnInvoke**) and Label(**lblText**) control inside the UpdatePanel. Also add a `<div id="divImage">` inside the **UpdatePanel**. This div will contain a **.gif** image that depicts progress and is initially set to invisible **`style="display:none"`**. On the button click, perform a time consuming task. In our case, we have set a delay of 3 seconds by using `Thread.Sleep(3000)`

C#

```
protected void btnInvoke_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        lblText.Text = "Processing completed";
    }
```

Took from **[here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=227)**